# Best shade grass seed for north central Florida?

Tags: grass, seeds, shade

I just completed a lot of underground plumbing work in my backyard which has resulted in me having lots of patches of dirt, and I would like to plant grass seed to start to add some ground cover.

I'm located in north central Florida and this area is in shade most of the day. What grass seed can I plant now (Fall/Winter) which will do well in shade? I'm aware of annual rye grass, which will provide quick ground cover, but I'm hoping to plant something that will live year round.

The rest of my backyard is mostly weeds, so I don't really care about mixing grass types.

Thank you for any guidance you can provide.

Comment: I would put out the annual rye seed right now and then hope to find shade grass for next spring. The rye will die back in warm weather.